# Update Mysql record with partial data from same row

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table with latitude and longitude concatenated together in a single field with a comma/space separating the values.  It was poor planning as now I need to break latitude and longitude into separate fields.

So, I added 2 new fields to the table and need to populate them based on the existing data in the table.  The new fields are set to decimal(6,9) it it appears the data rounds even if a larger number of digits are passed through the update query.

It looks like this:

```
ID   LOCATION                         LAT        LONG
1     43.12345,-118.12345           0.000000    0.000000
2     43.11223999, -118.43232997    0.000000    0.000000
```

I want to write 2 queries:
1) Update TABLE set LAT= LOCATION, but where it takes the first group of characters, from the first digit to just before the comma

2) Update TABLE set LONG= LOCATION, but where it takes the group of characters, from the comma/space ", " through the end of the text string.

I"m not sure if this is a reg-ex thing, or if I should be using a combination of substr or some other functions to use on the text.

Any help finding direction of this much appreciated as always.

thanks...

Comment: Don't you mean `DECIMAL(9,6)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this simply:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TBL
SET    LAT    = CAST(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(LOCATION, ',',  1)) AS DECIMAL(9,6)),
       `LONG` = CAST(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(LOCATION, ',', -1)) AS DECIMAL(9,6))
```